# How to access private or protected methods from superclass with reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, protected

It is do possible to access `private` or `protected` methods with [`getDeclaredMethod()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29). Resulting method instance can be made accessible with [`setAccessible()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible%28boolean%29) and invoked.

But this technique allows to access "downmost" classe's method. Is it possible to access methods from superclass similarly?

I am doing service class which is used similar to [`PropertyChangeSupport`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeSupport.html) class and which requires to access `firePropertyChange` method, which is `protected` in most implementations.

**UPDATE**

Suppose we don't want to hack overriding. I mean, we wish to find downmost protected method.

Comment: Arguably, if there is an implementation of a method in a subclass, it is incorrect to try and access the implementation in the superclass. The only valid place from which a superclass implementation should be accessible is an immediate subclass.

Comment: Yes, suppose we want to reach downmost method

Comment: Subclasseses overriding methods is a cornerstone of OOP. Even thinking about subverting that is a bad idea. Oh, and it can't be done in java (by design).

Comment: I don't want to subverte